# Thriller movie about a (bad/mean) twin who reaches and tries to trade places with her twin sister through lucid dreams

Tags: identify-this-movie

I can't remember almost anything about this movie.

---

**Film genre:** Probably a thriller (or mystery? idk)
**Year of release:** I was really young at the time, so maybe around 2000 to 2009
**Language:** Definitely English (probably from USA)

**Characters:** So from what I can remember, the protagonist was a blonde girl, between 17-18 (she was a teen). She also had a male friend who helped her through the story. (kind of love interest?)

**Plot:** The girl has a twin sister, but they were separated (probably at birth, can't remember, but they didn't grow up together because she doesn't know anything about her) and now her twin is trying to reach her by talking to her. This sister is trapped in an asylum or a psychiatric hospital and the only thing she wants is to trade places with her sister (she wants the other one to be trapped instead). I think she starts to speak to her through some kind of "power"/bond between twins and teachs her how to "lucid dream" (I don't how to say it, but this is the way she wants to trade places with her). The other sister really wants to help her, so does what she asks, and I can't remember how she figures it out, but she does. She never trades places with her because she finds out and either the other twin stays trapped forever or actually dies. (can't remember...)

---

I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm sorry if there are some mistakes. I looked for this movie for so long, seriously. I just can't find it. Unfortunately this is all I know about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like [Stranger with My Face](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375790/combined) from 2009.

> After the shocking and untimely death of her husband, Shelley Stratton (Catherine Hicks) moves her daughter Alexis (Emily Hurst) and her adopted daughter, Laurie (Alexz Johnson), to their remote summer house in hopes of giving her family a fresh start. As Laurie begins to settle in and put her life back together, she gets the eerie feeling that she is constantly being watched. Laurie's uneasiness grows when people start claiming to see her in places that she has never been. The family's delicate state begins to unravel when **Laurie unearths the dark past, discovering a twin sister that she never knew she had. Laurie is forced to delve deeper into her twin's secrets, for as it turns out her twin has been locked up for years! Laurie must now understand their strange connection in order to prevent her sister from taking over her life** and harming her loved ones.

Her sister contacts her through astral projection. Based on a [YA book from 1981](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_with_My_Face). Here's the trailer: